# How to open program made by access in design mode?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a program made and developed by Microsoft access 2003 but i can't open it's VBA code or see any tables or use the design mode even by using alt + F11

it's only open the program interface

so how i can do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the application has been compiled to a mde (or accDE), then design mode will not be available for forms/reports and VBA code.

Assuming you have an mdb or accDB (not an mde or accDE in which design changes are NOT possible), then you should and can modify the application.

The first suggestion to hold down the shift key during application startup usually works. However, the shift key can be disabled. That being the case, then simply create a new blank database and then import all objects from the original - this thus will allow you to launch/open the application without any startup code running.

Comment: I don't think you're able to import any stand alone classes or modules though, so hopefully, there aren't too many in the app.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by pressing shift key while opening the mdb.